# Citation "" on page X undefined on line Y

Tags: bibtex

I have a references.bib file where I have a lot of references, i.e:

```
@article{karl,
    title = {{Motion Planning for Parking a Truck and Trailer System}},
    year = {2019},
    journal = { Master Thesis KTH},
    author = {Karl Kvarnfors}
}

@article{differential_flatness,
    title = {{Flatness and defect of non-linear systems: Introductory theory and examples}},
    year = {1995},
    journal = {International Journal of Control, 61(6)},
    author = {M. Fliess, J. Lévine, P. Martin, and P. Rouchon}
}
```

If I do `\cite{karl}` it plots [4] but if `\cite{differential_flatness}` it plots [**differential_flatness**]. Do you know why?

Comment: The appropriate separator for authors is "and". Comma is used to distinguish first and last name. I.e. it should be like this `author = {M. Fliess and J. Lévine and P. Martin and P. Rouchon}`

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.  Cannot say much without seeing the code that generates the issue (even just a small test file; not your full document). Did you compile twice? Is the keyword spelled correctly in the `\cite` command in the code? Did you edit the `.bib` file but not save it?